# compare two arrays with array_diff

Tags: php, arrays

i got two multidimensional arrays and i'm trying to subtract all the values from the second array in the first array.

1st array : named $arrayREQ2

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [subject] => asdasd 
        [from_id] => 3 
        [to_id] => 5 
        [time] => 2014-05-11 10:58:33 
    ) 

    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [subject] => trolis 
        [from_id] => 4 
        [to_id] => 3 
        [time] => 2014-05-08 16:09:30 
    ) 
    [2] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [subject] => bandom 
        [from_id] => 3 
        [to_id] => 5 
        [time] => 2014-05-08 11:50:39 
    ) 
)
```

Second : named `$arrayREQ1`

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 2 
        [subject] => trolis 
        [from_id] => 4 
        [to_id] => 3 
        [time] => 2014-05-08 16:09:30 
    ) 
)
```

And my expecting result :

```
Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [id] => 3 
        [subject] => asdasd 
        [from_id] => 3 
        [to_id] => 5 
        [time] => 2014-05-11 10:58:33 
    )  

    [1] => Array ( 
        [id] => 1 
        [subject] => bandom 
        [from_id] => 3 
        [to_id] => 5 
        [time] => 2014-05-08 11:50:39 
    ) 
)
```

I tried use array_diff but it doesn't work:

```
$diffff = array_diff($arrayREQ2, $arrayREQ1);
```

it returns empty array.

Comment: This might be helpful http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php#98680

Comment: Do you receive any error messages?

Comment: no i just get empty array

Comment: `This function only checks one dimension of a n-dimensional array.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If want, you could just use plain ol' foreach on this. They check if it matches, if yes, unset that particular key. Consider this example:

```
$arrayREQ1 = array(array('id' => 2, 'subject' => 'trollis', 'from_id' => 4, 'to_id' => 3, 'time' => '2014-05-08 16:09:30'));
$arrayREQ2 = array(
    array('id' => 3, 'subject' => 'asdasd', 'from_id' => 3, 'to_id' => 5, 'time' => '2014-05-11 10:58:33'),
    array('id' => 2, 'subject' => 'trollis', 'from_id' => 4, 'to_id' => 3, 'time' => '2014-05-08 16:09:30'),
    array('id' => 1, 'subject' => 'bandom', 'from_id' => 3, 'to_id' => 5, 'time' => '2014-05-08 11:50:39'),
);

foreach($arrayREQ2 as $key => $value) {
    if($arrayREQ1[0] === $value) {
        unset($arrayREQ2[$key]);
    }
}

print_r($arrayREQ2);
```

Sample Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 3
        [subject] => asdasd
        [from_id] => 3
        [to_id] => 5
        [time] => 2014-05-11 10:58:33
    )

    [2] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [subject] => bandom
        [from_id] => 3
        [to_id] => 5
        [time] => 2014-05-08 11:50:39
    )

)
```